# Intersect method in LINQ with C#

Tags: c#, linq, intersect

I am trying to obtain the same files using Intersect method from two folders.
123.xml files are the same (no change with content, date, size) in all the folders.

```
Scores\Content\123.xml
Scores\Content\hi.xml
Scores\123.xml

Power\Content\123.xml
Power\Content\helo.xml
Power\123.xml
```

This is from the C# code

```
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir1 = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(path1);
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir2 = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(path2);

        IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> list1 = dir1.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> list2 = dir2.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        FileCompare myFileCompare = new FileCompare();

        bool areIdentical = list1.SequenceEqual(list2, myFileCompare);

        if (areIdentical == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("the two folders are the same");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The two folders are not the same");
        }


        var queryCommonFiles = list1.Intersect(list2, myFileCompare);
```

The queryCommonFiles is only returning the 123.xml from Content folder, but not the other one.

This is the code from the FileCompare

```
class FileCompare : System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<System.IO.FileInfo>
{

    public FileCompare() { }

    public bool Equals(System.IO.FileInfo f1, System.IO.FileInfo f2)
    {
        return (f1.Name == f2.Name &&
                f1.Length == f2.Length);
    }

    // Return a hash that reflects the comparison criteria. According to the 
    // rules for IEqualityComparer<T>, if Equals is true, then the hash codes must
    // also be equal. Because equality as defined here is a simple value equality, not
    // reference identity, it is possible that two or more objects will produce the same
    // hash code.
    public int GetHashCode(System.IO.FileInfo fi)
    {
        string s = String.Format("{0}{1}", fi.Name, fi.Length);
        return s.GetHashCode();
    }

}
```

EDIT:

```
var queryList1Only = (from file in list1
                                  select file).Except(list2, myFileCompare);

            Console.WriteLine("The following files are in list1 but not list2:\n");
            foreach (var v in queryList1Only)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(v.FullName);
            }


            var queryList2Only = (from file in list2
                                  select file).Except(list1, myFileCompare);

            Console.WriteLine("The following files are in list2 but not list1:\n");
            foreach (var v in queryList2Only)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(v.FullName);
            }
```

This produces as hi.xml for list1 and helo.xml for list2. And as I said only one 123.xml for the intersect method.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Thanks,

Comment: Is it because "list1.Intersect" is actually comparing just the file names rather than the file names with folder structure ?

Comment: I suggest you put some diagnostics into the Equals and GetHashCode methods... I expect the other files have different lengths, or something like that.

Comment: @superstar the Name atribute in FileInfo does not have the path

Comment: @Adrian: I saw that, I cannot use FullName there, since the folder structure for both the Scores and Power differs.

Comment: If I have different lenghts or any difference in the two 123.xml files, I should get them in the comparison (under the EDIT), but I am getting only hi.xml in list1 and helo.xml for list2 as the differences

Comment: @Adrian: Your comment helped me to check into it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just changed the Equals method to achieve the desired results

```
class FileCompare : System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<System.IO.FileInfo>
    {

        public FileCompare() { }

        public bool Equals(System.IO.FileInfo f1, System.IO.FileInfo f2)
        {
            return (f1.Name == f2.Name && f1.Directory.Name == f2.Directory.Name && 
                    f1.Length == f2.Length);
        }

        // Return a hash that reflects the comparison criteria. According to the 
        // rules for IEqualityComparer<T>, if Equals is true, then the hash codes must
        // also be equal. Because equality as defined here is a simple value equality, not
        // reference identity, it is possible that two or more objects will produce the same
        // hash code.
        public int GetHashCode(System.IO.FileInfo fi)
        {
            string s = String.Format("{0}{1}", fi.Name, fi.Length);
            return s.GetHashCode();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Everything looks OK. Make sure both `Scores\123.xml` and `Power\123.xml` have the same length.

Comment: They do have the same length, date and content. (I just copied the same file to both the folders)

Answer (score 2):

Because you only compare using FileInfo.Name and FileInfo.Length, Content\123.xml is the same as 123.xml (assuming both files have the same size, which I'm guessing is the case for your test data).

Therefore, as far as your FileCompare class is concerned, your input collections contain duplicates. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408.aspx), Intersect evaluates **distinct** elements in each set.

Comment: Yes, Intersect evaluates distinct elements.

Comment: Therefore, distinct elements of [123.xml, hi.xml, 123.xml] and [123.xml, helo.xml, 123.xml] are [123.xml, hi.xml] and [123.xml, helo.xml]. The intersection of these is the single element 123.xml.

Comment: But I needed same files to be identified, so I modified the Equals method to handle it.